# How to set activeOffsetX of PanGestureHandler in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-gesture-handler, react-native-reanimated-v2

I have a list of messages and I'm making feature swipe to reply using PanGestureHandler, I want to limit area swipeable by props activeOffsetX, how can I achieve this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhk6f.png)

> ```
> > <PanGestureHandler
> > enabled={!isInfoText}
> > activeOffsetX={
> > isMyMessage ? [-POSITION_X, 0] : [0, POSITION_X]
> >         }
> > onGestureEvent={_onHandleSwipe}>
> > PanGestureHandler>
> ```

Limit the area swipeable

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `GestureDetector`to achieve the pan gesture. It's worked for me to set `activeOffsetX` using below code:

```
const panGesture = Gesture.Pan().activeOffsetX(isMyMessage ? [-POSITION_X, 0] : [0, POSITION_X]);

<GestureDetector gesture={panGesture}>
 <your code>
</GestureDetector>
```